# Error compiling pcl_ros on Fuerte

Tags: pcl, macos, ros-fuerte, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble getting pcl_ros to compile on OSX. I forked rosdistro and created the rosdep for pcl, I also upgraded my XCode to 4.3.2 and installed the command line tools. I also got rid of XCode 4.2 and its command line tools. I get this huge [error message](https://gist.github.com/2604784) when I compile it with the first error shown below:

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:121:15: error: no member named
  '__s_getMD5Sum' in 'pcl::PointIndices'
return M::__s_getMD5Sum().c_str();
```

I have tried to fix this but can't figure it out. I think it has something to do with dynamic_reconfigure, but not sure. Take a look at the complete error message linked above and let me know what I am missing.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33335/error-compiling-pcl_ros-on-fuerte/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2012-05-05**:
Is this a related issue? http://answers.ros.org/question/11410/error-__s_getmd5sum-is-not-a-member

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-05**:
It may be related, but this is standard ros code (i.e., not mine) that compiles under linux, so I think it should be something simple like adding a boost library. I have already tried adding several to the link process, but nothing helps.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-06**:
I this this issue has to do with [dynamic_reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure), but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is broke and doesn't work on OSX

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1